# VB.Net module behavior

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am having a "weird" situation of my VB.Net modules, as per my understanding, `Module` in VB.Net means static class so I have implemented a couple of helper modules with couple of functions each, let's have some examples for better explanation (free hand code, may contains syntax problem):

```
Namespace Helpers
    Module HelperA
        Public Function FunctionA() As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace

Namespace Helpers
    Module HelperB
        Public Function FunctionB() As Integer
            Return 1
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

When I start coding in Visual Studio and type `Helpers.`, both `FunctionA()` and `FunctionB()` are show up in the recommended auto-complete dialog which I have not type `HelperA` or `HelperB` yet, I have some C#.Net projects with static class and I found such behavior does not apply to C#.Net static class.

It is weird to me and inconvenience since I am now having 50-ish functions under a single namespace, have done some Google but nothing could be find, could anyone suggest a solution (besides change `Module` to `Class`) or any keywords to search with?

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Module` doesn't technically mean static class. Static in VB.net (with regard to functions) is `Shared`, and there is no `Shared Class`. What I think you want is a sealed/abstract/not-inheritable class with static/shared functions (you'll be able to call the functions without an instance of the parent class, but you'll still have to reference the parent class when calling the function). If that's the case, then do something similar to the following:

```
Public NotInheritable Class HelperA
    Public Shared Function FunctionA() as Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Having said that, the only difference I've found—at least for practical purposes—between a shared function and a module function is that module functions can be called without referencing the module.

Comment: Thanks Lopsided! Glad you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: `Methods` in a `Module` appear in the `Module`'s parent namespace as well as inside the module itself. This was put in for syntax compatibility with VB6